# Auto-add site to "Your Communities" when clicking autocomplete

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, top-bar, autocomplete

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click Stack Exchange logo for dropdown in the top left of the SE bar
2. Click `edit` to the right of `Your Communities`
3. Start typing the name of any SE site  that isn't present in the list of `Your Communities`
4. Click the name of any site that isn't present in the list of `Your Communities`

This autocompletes the text in the `input`, but the user must still click <kbd>Add</kbd> to add it to their list.

---

I propose that clicking an autocomplete entry (excluding those highlighted because they are already present in the `Your Communities` list) automatically adds it to the list and clears the `input`.